# Bottom orbital velocity during a typical typhoon

Tags: waves, atmospheric-science, weather, oceanography

What is the wave orbital velocity generated during a typhoon? I cannot find direct measurements, so hoping to find a way to calculate this. In other words:

How do I get from wind speeds of 12 on the Beaufort scale to wave orbital velocity?

Let's say that with a Beaufort scale 12 wind goes at 120 km/h. I suppose wind-generated wave may start travelling at a similar speed (?), but this speed would not be the same as wave orbital velocity. What are the steps to take to convert to orbital velocity?

Comment: Quite a specialised technical question for this site. It would help if you provided some context for the question, eg define "wave orbital velocity." You might wish to post also in *Earth Science SE*.

Comment: http://eprints.hrwallingford.co.uk/692/1/TR155.pdf, http://eprints.hrwallingford.co.uk/761/1/SR76-method-calculating-orbital-velocity-waves.pdf

Comment: @sammygerbil, thanks, I was not sure where to post it, and thanks for referring me these materials. My understanding is now that I should calculate how much of the wind speed translates to wave travelling speed, from I should get the wave height and period, combined with water depth this will give bottom orbital velocity.

Comment: See table in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_wave